# Need help to solve issue in inner Join query

Tags: php, mysql

I need a join query for fetching data when I click a button. Click section is done with the help of PHP and jQuery. But join query is failed. Please help me to solve this issue.

I tried query is

```
    SELECT events.id,
                   form_values.id,
                   form_values.value,
                   form_fields.title,
                   form_fields.relation FROM events 
        INNER JOIN form_values 
    ON form_values.parent_id = events.customer_id
         INNER JOIN form_fields 
       ON form_fields.id = form_values.form_field_id 
WHERE form_fields.relation = 'event' AND events.id = '10029'
```

**form_fields** : Contains html input type details. For listing input types dynamically in to forms.

**form_values** : It is used to store dynamic values from input type.

**form_values**

form_field_id : related to `form_fields.id` table

parent_id     : related to `events.customer_id` table

```
id  form_field_id  value  parent_id

 1       2         3       3119
 2       5         yes     3119
 3       10        yes     3119
 4       10        yes     3118
 5       6         text    3118
 6       4         on      3118
```

**form_fields**

```
    id      title         type       option                         relation

    2       select box    select     2:CustomerTwo|3:CustomerThree  customer
    4       check box     checkbox                                  customer                                      
    5       radio one     radio      yes:Yes|no:No                  customer 
    6       text box      textbox                                   event  
   10       radio two     radio      yes:Yes|no:No                  event
```

**events**

```
 id        customer_id   title    price

 10028       3119        Test1     125
 10029       3118        Test2     132
 10030       3118        Test3     133
```

**Result I need is:**

When I click a button `id (events.id = 10029)` will pass and fetch data.
I need result where `form_fields.relation = "event"` and `events.id = clicked ID(10029, 10028)`

```
events.id   form_fields.value   form_fields.title  form_fields.relation
10029           text                 text box           event
10029           yes                  radio two          event
10028           yes                  radio two          event
```

Comment: change `events.id = '10029'` to `events.id in ('10029','10028')` in the where clause perhaps.  In will support one or multiple event id's at a cost of some performance.  Though... how can a click result in 2 ID's being selected.  I assume there's a checkbox or something in the PHP containing the multiple values being passed.

Comment: Well the `in` would still use an index in place

Answer (score 0):

I thing you have mistake in data entry, I run same query but I got the answer exactly you want, so check your data please, and the query I ran is `SELECT events.id, form_values.id, form_values.value, form_fields.title, form_fields.relation FROM events INNER JOIN form_values ON form_values.parent_id = events.customer_id INNER JOIN form_fields ON form_fields.id = form_values.form_field_id WHERE form_fields.relation = 'event' AND events.id IN('10029','10028')`